# Highslide: Shrink image back when clicking in outer area

Tags: image, highslide

The only thing which I disklike whith highslide is the fact that when I click a thumbnail and it gets bigger I only can shrink it back when I click exactly in the image area.

Is it possible to shrink the image back when clicking outside the image area?

(and optional also shrink it back when I hover outside the image with the mouse cursor?)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a dimming background (hs.dimmingOpacity=0.7, for example), clicking outside the image area will close the expander. This requires highslide-full.js. If you don't want a dimming background, just set the opacity to a tiny value, like hs.dimmingOpacity=0.01.

It might be possible to include an onAfterExpand event to close the expander when you hover outside the image, but I think I can guarantee that you wouldn't like it. If a visitor clicked on a thumbnail, but didn't just happen to have his mouse over the image when it opened, it would immediately close again. That would be *very* frustrating behavior for the site visitor.

Comment: Any idea how to make it close on 'click', regardless of were the click is?

Comment: As I said, if you use a dimming background, it will close if you click anywhere - on the image, or outside the image. An example: http://highslide.com/examples/gallery-floating-caption.html